# Charging a laptop not in use for 3 years

Tags: laptop, battery

My laptop has been unplugged for about 3 years. Will the battery still be good, and how long should I charge it on the initial re-plug?

Comment: Most battery chargers are fairly "intelligent", and stop charging if the battery is unusable. Though you could try bringing it back in a few steps, rather than all at once, it's doubtful of any use. Likely, the battery has been permanently damaged by deep discharge, but you have nothing to lose by trying.

Comment: its really going to depend on the type of battery (chemical composition).

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely the battery will still be good but it really depends on how it was stored and if there was any vampire drain.

In the ideal world, if the battery had 50% charge when you stored it, no vampire drain and kept in a cool environment (ie less then 20c) it should be fine.  On the other extreme if it was drained completely and sat in that state for months it will be quite damaged.

Without knowing the battery, no one can advise how long it will take to charge, but "until full" - it does not need to "trickle charge"

Comment: https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries has good information about the effects of storing batteries with respect of initial charge and temperature.

Answer (score 0):

To know if battery is still good, assuming that the laptop switches on when plugged into the mains, note the charging time till full capacity and then discharging time till fully exhausted. You may wish to use a "battery profiler" program for your OS (look it up in an internet search) to answer this question in certainty.

As for how long you should charge it, it should be as long as you used to do so for a full power cycle before you left it unplugged for years. A laptop from around 8 to 10 years ago would typically require 3 to 6 hours. Newer ones may require 2 to 5 hours. Also, it is okay to turn on the laptop while it is charging to check if it switches on and that the critical devices or peripherals are in working order. If it boots to the OS login without any complaint, you may be all good on that worry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).